# VBA code crashes after saving - says the situation lies with the XML "Run-time error '429'

Tags: vba, excel

I made a worksheet for the company I work for to help with pricing out custom designs. A few months ago I made a macro that can save the parts to a text file that can be pulled from at a later date if we wanted to quote out the same design. Everything was working perfectly, until one day I go to open it up and got the error message

```
We found a problem with some content in 'File.xlsm'. Do you want us to try 
to recover as much as we can?
```

When I click yes, it then comes up with the worksheet the macro was on completely un-formatted and says it could only open the file by repairing or removing the following part

```
Repaired Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml part.
```

This is weird because the only xml code I use is just to create a drop-down menu when the saved design names are loaded. Nothing has changed since the final revision of the code other than the amount of designs that have been saved. The boxes I had as buttons tied to macros have been deleted and none of the code for this sheet works. What it shows when I view the code now is [Sheet_Thumbnails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c33uu.jpg)

All other macros work, the other sheets are fully functional. When I try and run the code on this sheet I get

```
Run-time error '429':

ActiveX component can't create object
```

This has to be when compiling because I can't even debug where this is happening. The best answer I get when I look this error up is that I am not using the "New" keyword when calling a file or object from somewhere else. But I have looked through my code and don't see anywhere that applies. Luckily a co-worker saved a copy off our server to her computer so I have a backup, but when I open this and run the macros then save and re-open, the same crash happens.

Here is the code with xml:

```
Sub MakeList(ByRef r As Range, ByRef Config As String)

r.Clear
If Not Config = "" Then
    r.Select
        With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Config
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me? I am at a total loss for why this has happened and why it keeps happening. Is it the validation part? Why would it happen after working for months?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT 1**

Exporting all of the code and creating a new workbook did not solve the problem.

Thanks to Profex, the problem has been found and is in the validation. Essentially one of my lists was too long. The formula used in validation is not supposed to be beyond 255 characters. Even though Excel doesn't give any warning on this, when I would create the drop down menus, although it would populate each item from the list, after saving closing and re-opening, apparently this would corrupt the coded sheet. So now the question lies with how to add values into a drop-down menu without clearing and re-initializing with a longer list. Should I post a new question for that?

Comment: Sometimes a workbook can get corrupted after multiple changes to your code. I'd start by "cleaning" the workbook: export all of the code modules, then delete them from the workbook and re-import them.  Or use the excellent tool here:  http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm

Comment: this is related to the file being corrupted, and I don't think you can easily repair the VBAProject. Probably better to copy everything in a new file, or save the file as .xlsx (that will remove the VBAProject from the file), copy the code over, and save back as the original extension

Comment: Xslx files are zip files containing mostly xml files of your spreadsheet. Rename one to zip and browse it's contents. PS xls files are compound documents which means they are like a zip file holding other files (but different technology) - See http://docfileviewer.wedding-soft.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel, Cell Validation Lists have a 8191 character limit (which is way too long for a user to pick from anyway).

**Anything over 254 characters will corrupt the file upon save/re-open.**

Here is something similar to what I have done in the past to create ***Dynamic Validations lists:***

It uses your `MakeList()` subroutine, and requires another `GetList()` function to get the validation list for the specified cell.

Since this code is in the Workbook module, I also added another function called `IsSheetTheOneICareAboutWithValidations()`.  If you use the `WorksSheet_SelectionChange` Event from in a specific sheet module, this isn't required; but you would have to change the scope of `m_ValidationCell` and `m_ValidationList` to be `Public`.

This code is *untested* and goes in the ***ThisWorkbook*** module:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_ValidationCell As Excel.Range
Private m_ValidationList As String

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not m_ValidationCell Is Nothing Then
        m_ValidationList = m_ValidationCell.Validation.Value
        m_ValidationCell.Validation.Delete
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    If m_ValidationList <> vbNullString Then
        With m_ValidationCell.Validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=ValidationList
        End With
        m_ValidationList = vbNullString
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not m_ValidationCell Is Nothing Then
        m_ValidationCell.Validation.Delete
        Set m_ValidationCell = Nothing
    End If

    If IsSheetTheOneICareAboutWithValidations(Sh) Then
        ' Since we're changing the Validation each time there is a new Selection;
        ' It's the Active Cell that matters, not the Target range
        '   Add a validation list to any cell in column 4, after the header (in row 1).
        If ActiveCell.Column = 4 And ActiveCell.Row > 1 Then
            List = GetList(ActiveCell)
            MakeList ActiveCell, List
            ' Should probably add this next line to you MakeList() function
            Set m_ValidationCell = ActiveCell
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetList(Target As Range) As String
    GetList = vbNullString ' or whatever you want
End Function

Private Function IsSheetTheOneICareAboutWithValidations(Sh As Object) As Boolean
    IsSheetTheOneICareAboutWithValidations = (Sh.Name = "Pricing")
End Function
```

Comment: This is quite the workaround but seems to work. Thank you for all your help in this matter @Profex. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### ***Recovery***

It looks like you just had a bad save.  Sometimes it just corrupts the file and there isn't much you can do, other then hope you have a backup.

**Right Click** in the ***Folder*** **> Properties > Previous Versions**

---

If you don't have a backup, it might just help to move everything to a new file.

- **Create** a ***New Workbook***
- **Select All cells** from your ***first sheet*** (click above the 1, left of the A)
- Press **Ctrl+C** to Copy
- **Select All cells** in your ***New Workbook/Sheet***
- Press **Ctrl+V** to Paste
- **Repeat** for all ***Worksheets***

On the VB side of things, you can just **Drag** the ***Forms/Modules/Classes*** from the ***Old file*** to the ***New One***.

### ***Issue***

Did you know that all **New *Office* documents** are really just **ZIP** files...

Go ahead, **rename** the file to ***File.xlsm.zip***

Inside the file you'll see a folder structure which should have ...`/xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml`

This is what excel is complaining about!  That file is either missing or wrong.

### ***Code***

I don't know how you're calling `Makelist`, so I can't verify that the range `R` that you are passing is valid.

Please remove the `Select/Selection` from your code.  You don't need to select anything in the front end GUI of Excel to access/change the cells.  Also you didn't check if `R` was `Nothing`.

```
Sub MakeList(ByRef r As Range, ByRef Config As String)
If Not r Is Nothing then 
    r.Clear
    If Not Config = "" Then    
        With r.Validation
            ...
        End With     
    End If 
End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: I will try this out and re-create the workbook. I have saved a different copy of this same workbook which works fine until the code is ran and the lists are updated. Could this be due to the txt file? Either the size of it or how I'm calling it? If I were to re-create the workbook and copy the code over, what would be different that running a previous version of the workbook?

Comment: Yes, there is a size limit.  It will work fine in the current session, but will fail if it's saved and then re-opened.  Anything longer then 256 chars will corrupt the file & force all Validations to be lost.

Comment: Looking at my past code, it looks like there is limit of 8190 characters on validations lists;  But again anything over 256 characters will corrupt the file then next time you try to open it.

Comment: I didn't know of this limitation. Is that for each validation or is that the limit of the txt file I am using? If that's the limit of the txt file then what else could I use to store designs?

Comment: That's a validation/cell limit.

Comment: So I just tried moving everything over to a brand new workbook, exported and imported the coded sheets, modules, and forms. Ran the code again and same thing happened. Unless you or the community knows of a better way to validate and make lists, I am thinking I just have to format my strings to be no bigger than 256 characters.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, truncated the list before the last comma before character 253 (equal sign not included).  If you really want a longer list, up to 8190 chars, you'll need to manage it using dynamically generated validation lists or something else and kill them before save.